# Container delete items async for large quantities of id

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm fairly new to cosmos db, and I have a function that deletes the entries of a record. Currently I'm using this method "container.DeleteItemsAsync". It is working, but the problem is, whenever I try to delete thousands of ids, I received a time out. Is there a method that supports batch deletion?

Comment: Can you share your code for how you are doing the deletes? Are you dispatching each as its own Task and then awaiting them with a .WhenAll()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled `Bulk mode` and try deleting the documents? It should work the same way for  Create

```
 _client = new CosmosClient(connectionString, new CosmosClientOptions() { AllowBulkExecution = true });

// Delete item with 'id':
var partitionKey = new PartitionKey(id);
tasks.Add(_devicesContainer.DeleteItemStreamAsync(id, partitionKey));

// Wait processing to finish
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this one, by the way, what's the composition of connectionString? Is it Endpoint, key and database?

Comment: yeah right! you could get it from the portal

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I saw that there's a bulk executor library for this, what's the advantage of you posted over it?

Comment: Yes you are right. The advantage here that it comes with built in SDK

Comment: Read more about here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/

Comment: Bulk executor library is the old component for the old SDK, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/bulk-executor-dot-net) says to use Bulk Mode on the V3 SDK instead.